# Firebase :: Best way to structure this data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to use firebase to store and retrieve data for my application.. i know that it is recommended to denormalize data and that it may require data replication..

my scenario is as follows:

1. there are a number of users in the system..
2. there are a number of posts in the system..
3. any user should be able to get a list of posts for a particular user..
4. each posts has a number of users as participants..

i am tempted to use the following structure for this:

```
users: {
    abc: {
        name: 'UserA',
        profilePicture: 'imageA.png'
    },
    pqr: {
        name: 'UserB',
        profilePicture: 'imageB.png'
    },
    xyz: {
        name: 'UserC',
        profilePicture: 'imageC.png'
    },
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
},
posts: {
    def: {
        title: 'PostA',
        users: {
            abc: true,
            def: true,
            ghi: true,
            ...,
            ...,
            ...
        }
    },
    stu: {
        title: 'PostB',
        users: {
            abc: true,
            xyz: true,
            ...,
            ...,
            ...
        }
    },
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
}
```

the issue with this is that if i need to show a list of users with each post, i will need to make a query to `POST`, and then make sequential calls to `USER` for each user inside that post to get the `name/profilePicture` data..

if i replicate the user info inside posts as well, the issue becomes that if a user later changes her `profilePicture` or `name`, then existing posts will still show the old data..

how can i structure this data better so these cases are efficient?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replicate data inside posts. Read [Firebase Docs about structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Best practices:

- Avoid nesting data
- Flatten data structures

if you include data in post you are breaking those 2 rules (and you don't want it).

Multiple calls are not bad.

Comment: right now, im not replicating data.. but this is forcing me to make multiple server calls, anyone of which can fail or be delayed.. i would prefer downloading 100kb of data once instead of making 10 sequential calls each bringing in about 10kb..

Comment: i think i should stand corrected.. i think i was under the false pretense that everytime you call `ref.once('value')`, there would be an HTTP request and response (which would be IMMENSELY slow).. instead i now believe that firebase opens a socket at the client which makes data transfers lightening fast.. please correct me if that is so.. if this is the case, then denormalization should not be an issue at all.. =)

Comment: Firebase uses sockets (that is why there is something like 
Simultaneous connections in Firebase pricing) so denormalization is not bad. I should have explained why *Multiple calls are not bad*. So Firebase didn't screw up, they thought about it.